# UINavigationBar seems to pop 2 items off stack on "back"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm manually managing a UINavigationBar for my view.  The Bar itself and the first UINavigationItem are created in Interface Builder.  In my code, based upon various events, I push new navigation items onto the bar and paint the appropriate views as subviews of the main view.  It all seems fine, but when I select the navbar back button, two items are lopped off the items stack, rather than 1 as I would have expected.  To test, I set my controller as the delegate for the bar and trap 2 delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item;
```

and

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item;
```

I found right before the pop, the items in the nav bar is correct, for example, 3.  In the second method, just after the pop, the items is 1, even though the item popped is the last item - somehow the middle item is missing.  I'm stumped as to how to debug this and would appreciate any ideas.

Note that I'm not using a navigation controller for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

check if the poppage is user initiated or programmatic like so

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = self.topViewController;

    ... some logic that justifies implementing shouldPopItem: delegate in the first place -> others have explained the caveats so I won't repeat that ...

    // manual as in opposite of programmatic
    BOOL manualPop = topViewController.navigationItem == item;
    if(manualPop) {
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm manually managing a
>   UINavigationBar for my view."

Don't do that. ;-)

Seriously. I can't think of a good reason to manage it yourself and if you're not very careful  you'll run into issues that make the whole app unmanageable. So why not just create a UINavigationController in your root view that is connected to your XIB? What problem are you trying to overcome by managing the nav bar yourself?

As to the problem you're having--you get two pops because you are doing something in shouldPopItem that is telling it to pop again. That is an effect of trying to manage the nav bar yourself. Keep in mind that the shouldPopItem and didPopItem only relate to the nav bar and not the navigation controller and views. When you pop a view controller with [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; it will call shouldPopItem. Since you are overriding that, you have to manage everything.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I was thinking that perhaps something was calling didPopItem and shouldPopItem twice, which is why I set up the delegate methods so I could trap these.  They're only called once.  

At the time it seemed easier to extend my viewcontroller than to implement the navigation controller.  And given that IB gives you the tools to set this up, I figured it would be OK.  Plus, I'm fairly new to iphone dev and like to understand the framework mechanics.  I've worked my way around it now, and chalked this up to yet another thing with the environment that has evaded my understanding...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by placing an `NSLog()` statement at the beginning of your `shouldPopItem` and `didPopItem` methods - this will give you an idea of how many times they're getting called, and when. Next, you can log the size of the view controller stack at various places throughout your app, so you can watch it grow and shrink. If neither of those work, just start placing breakpoints and checking stack traces/view controller stack size manually.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't very clean in my post - this is exactly what I was doing - setting breakpoints and viewing the size of the stack and what's on the stack.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost never, ever acceptable to replace or exclude core classes like `UINavigationController`. Trust me, I've seen someone who did this extensively, and the app was rife with issues—and I had to deal with them. Just take a look at `UINavigationController.h`. It's managing a ton of state, etc. Why are you trying to manage your own navigation bar?

Instead, it's acceptable to "lightly" subclass classes like `UINavigationBar` to override only certain drawing/layout methods. Doing so lets all the complicated logic fall back to the base classes as intended.

Even better, just make use of the `contents` property of the navigation bar if all you're looking to do is style it with, say, a custom image:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage * navigationBarContents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents =
        (id)navigationBarContents.CGImage;
}
```

You can do this for any `UIView` subclass to easily and cleanly change the way they look using images. Of course, if you're doing custom drawing, just subclass `UINavigationBar` and override only the `-drawRect:` method. Then use that subclass in place of `UINavigationBar` with a standard `UINavigationController`, and everything will function exactly as it normally would, only with your custom-style navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why UINavigationBar behaves like this, but I have a tricky solution.

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar
    shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    NSMutableArray *items = navigationBar.items.mutableCopy;
    [items removeObject:item];

    // Now var 'items' contains the proper instances of UINavigationItem. To be exact, one more than the instances in 'navigationBar.items'.

    return YES;
}
```